# Determining fully (or sufficiently) qualified rpm package name from short name

Tags: centos, yum, rpm

Yum has some sort of built-in "semantic sugar" which does a translation of short-hand package names to actual package names, but I can't figure out how to easily get a hold of it.

Here's a simple repro:

1. `yum install vim` *(completes successfully, installs vim-enhanced-some-version...)*
2. `rpm -q vim` *(reports not installed)*
3. `yum info vim` *(no matching packages)*
4. `yum install vim` *(vim-enhanced-blah-blah-blah already installed...)*

Also, doing `rpm -qa | grep "vim-"` lists 4 packages but no way to easily figure out the "root" package that is the logical equivalent of just running `yum install vim`.

How can I figure out a sufficiently qualified package name so that I can do rpm or yum queries on it without having to do some silly dance with scraping the output from yum install?

Answer (score 2):

Always use yum.  `yum provides vim`

```
2:vim-enhanced-7.4.629-6.el7.x86_64 : A version of the VIM editor which includes recent enhancements
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Provides    : vim = 7.4.629-6.el7
```

Explicit provides like this are rare in packaging. yum can also search name, file names, or automatically generated library provides from the linker.